# Apparent logical flaw in statement: ∀x∀yP(x,y)⊢∀x∀yP(y,x)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I was able to prove the statement $\forall{x} \forall{y} P(x,y) \vdash \forall{x} \forall{y} P(y,x)$:

[image: Proof of statement]

This implies order does not matter within predicates. However, this confuses me because depending on what the predicate represents, order can be crucial.

Take, for example $P(x,y)$ representing $x < y$ with the universe of discourse for $x$ being all negative integers and the UOD for y being all positive integers.

In this case, $\forall{x} \forall{y} P(x,y)$ holds since all negative integers are smaller than all positive integers.

However, $\forall{x} \forall{y} P(y,x)$ would not hold since all positive integers are not smaller than all negative integers.

Clearly, I am misunderstanding something or making incorrect assumptions about the nature of predicate logic. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\forall x$ commutes with $\forall y$.

Comment: The predicate you chose, $P(x,y) \leftrightarrow x < y$, does not satisfy the premise $\forall x.\forall y. P(x,y)$ of your proof. There is always only one domain of discourse, and all your variables range over that same domain. And your proof does not show that order of arguments never matters. Only that it does not matter *if* your predicate is always true, i.e. if it holds for all $x,y$.

Comment: But the premise simply says that everything is P-connected.

Comment: The error seems to be in your statement that "this implies order does not matter within predicates." That's true in some (very limited) contexts, like the one in your proof, where both variables are universally quantified over the same domain. But it's false in a lot of other contexts..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a general principle that $\forall x \forall y \ P(x,y)$ is logically equivalent to $\forall x \forall y \ P(y,x)$, and that is what you proved (well, technically, you showed that $\forall x \forall y \ P(x,y)$ logically implies $\forall x \forall y \ P(y,x)$, but a completlely analogous proof will show that it goes the other way around as well)

However, it is understood here that $x$ and $y$ come from the same domain. Indeed, the very use of $\forall x \forall y$ ... implies that $x$ and $y$ come from the same domain.

Now, if you want $x$ and $y$ to be from different domains, then there are a few options.

First, if you are allowed the use of restricted quantifiers, then you can do $\forall x \in X \forall y \in Y ....$, ... but there is no general principle that says that $\forall x \in X \forall y \in Y \ P(x,y)$ is equivalent to $\forall x \in X \forall y \in Y \ P(y,x)$ (indeed, as your example demonstrates, we better not make this an euivelence principle)

Second, if you are not allowed the use of restricted quantifiers, you can do: $\forall x \forall y ((x \in X \land y \in Y) \to P(x,y))$, but now note that with the general principle that would be equivalent to $\forall x \forall y ((y \in X \land x \in Y) \to P(y,x))$ ... and that is not the same as $\forall x \forall y ((x \in X \land y \in Y) \to P(y,x))$

Finally, maybe you have learned logic in a way where you can just stipulate that 'variable $x$ comes from this domain, and variable $y$ from this other'.  Well, you might get away with that in some informal setting, but given the hard principles of formal logic, the use of $\forall x \forall y ...$ still means that $x$ and $y$ must be from the same domain.

So no, your example with positive and negative numbers does not provide an exception to the equivalence principle or to your proof.